# Data pseudoinstruction in CPUSIM

Tags: assembly

We are required to create a machine in cpusim.This are the text instruction that are given by our Prof.

```
Start: load data1 ;
       add data2 ;
       store data1 ;
       load data3 ;
       add data1 ;
       store data1 ;
data1: .data 2 4 ;
data2: .data 2 2 ;
data3: .data 2 3
```

I would like to ask what does

data1: data 2 4;

data2: .data 2 2;

data3: data 2 3  stand for?

Comment: The [CpuSim manual](http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/CPUSim/CPUSim3.4UserManual.pdf) covers that.

Comment: It assembles literal data bytes into the output file, instead of instruction machine code.